# Same Step is repeated in multiple feature files but can not be used

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am learning cucumber framework but stuck at the following, searched the internet but could not get any specific idea.

```
Feature File 1:

Feature: Facebook title
#Scenario 1
Scenario: Verify the facebook title
Given the user is navigated to FB login page
Then the title should be correct
And close the browser

Feature File 2:

Feature: Google title
Scenario: Verify google title
Given user is navigated to google
Then verify the title
And close the browser

StepDefinitionGoogleTitle.java -code

public class StepDefinitionGoogleTitle extends setupchrome {
static WebDriver driver = setup();
@Given("^user is navigated to google$")
public void navitaetoGoogle() throws Throwable {
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}
@Then("^verify the title$")
public void verifytheTitle() throws Throwable {
Assert.assertEquals("Title is not as expected","Google",driver.getTitle());
}
@When("^enter something and search$")
public void searchTesxt() throws Throwable {
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("akash");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
}
@Then("^verify the title after search$")
public void verify_the_title_after_search() throws Throwable {
Assert.assertEquals("Title is not as expected","akash - Google Search",driver.getTitle());
}}

StepDefinitionFacebookTitle.java - code

public class StepDefinitionFacebookTitle extends setupchrome {
WebDriver driver = setup();
@And("^close the browser$")
public void closeTheBrowser() throws Throwable {
driver.close();
}}

setupchrome.java - code

public class setupchrome {
protected static WebDriver driver;
protected static WebDriver setup()
{
if(driver==null)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\D\\Jar FIles\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}
return driver;
}}
```

The step definition for the above feature files are written in two separate files.**For the common step Close the browser** i have written the method only in one file as if i add the method in both the file it will give a compile time error indicating duplicate step , but on running the file i am getting below error message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionatstepDefinition.StepDefinitionFacebookTitle.closeTheBrowser (StepDefinitionFacebookTitle.java:55)at ?.And close the browser(Gmail.feature:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel above said that it depends that what framework you are using. And I suspect that you got mixed up with your PageFactory/PageObjectModel and Step Definitions files. Keep Page Objects classes separate from Steps files.

It would be great if you can paste steps definitions files as well, so that we can have a look.

If you just started with Cucumber, you can also follow a simple tutorial [***here***](http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm-feature-file/)

Comment: the problem here is(i hope) the WebDriver instance is not passed to the StepDefinitionFacebookTitle class when closeTheBrowser()  method is called at the end of feature file 2. i have setup the chrome browser in setupchrome class and the other two class extends this class. can you help in this now ?

Comment: Just do a small change, rather then extending setupchrome , just use setupchrome .driver in the stepdefinition file and see if it works well. And with the help of hooks, initialize your driver. Till the time i try to bring a nice working example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you are using to run the tests but the problem you are facing comes from an uninitialized steps class, in this case `StepDefinitionFacebookTitle`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

Have a look at how to use `Before` and `After` hooks in order to start and close a browser. More on this [here](https://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, using of Before and After helps in this case,i have one other related doubt, suppose i have to use 'Given the user is navigated to FB login page' step in both the feature file, then how can this be dealt with ? how can i use the same step definition in both the feature file ?

Comment: Short answer would be, to instantiate `StepDefinitionFacebookTitle` inside the Google step definition class and the use it's methods. For example, in the Google class you add `private StepDefinitionFacebookTitle fbSteps = new StepDefinitionFacebookTitle();` and now you could use those methods. Please have a look here [link](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer) for the long answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your steps located and what you provided as value of glue for execution.
I would suggest to try [QAF gherkin_client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html). It provides easy configuration and reuse steps even across multiple projects. You just need to specify step provide package either in property file or in xml config file. Steps may be in your project or in one of the jar.

for instance here is in properties:

```
step.provider.pkg=my.steps.pkg
```

You can refer [qaf-step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)